# Understanding NotFound() Controller and How to Make a Variation

Tags: c#, webapi

I have an existing WEB API application in C# that was built by someone else.  The purpose is to load a survey in an angular app.  If it can't find the ID in the database, it returns a NotFound().  On the client application, there is a route module setup to look for '404' and route to the NotFound component which is a simple html page.

```
if (surveyID == null)
{
   return NotFound()
}
```

I am trying to create something similar but for an expired survey using a custom action result if there is such a thing and routing it to a static page.

```
if (surveyHasExpired)
{
   return HasExpired()
}
```

I realize the first one is built in but I would think there is something similar that would let me pass a component name and/or object with expired information.

Comment: Do you want redirect user if page with survey is expired?

Comment: The [code for `NotFound()`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ControllerBase.cs#L1769) shows that it just returns `new NotFoundResult()`. You can do something similar in a method you create, but you have to decide which HTTP code you want to return and pick the correct Result class.

Comment: Also, I'm guessing you're using ASP.NET Web API, but is that correct, or are you using ASP.NET Core?

Comment: Maybe the redirect is what I need.  The NotFound() ends up pointing to mysite.com/404 but I don't anywhere where it specifically routes to that.